# In every polygon circumscribed about a circle, there exist three sides that can form a triangle.

Tags: circles, polygons

How can one show that in every polygon circumscribed about a circle, there exist three sides that can form a triangle?

(This was posted by another user and then deleted while I was typing my answer.)

Comment: It's a perfectly good question, of course. Perhaps the previous poster deleted it because he found the answer and then decided that he didn't need to ask it.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the very longest side and the two sides adjacent to it.

Say the longest side has vertices $B$ and $C$ and touches the circle at $Y$.  One of the adjacent sides shares vertex $B$ and touches the circle at $X$.  The other shares $C$ and touches at $Z$.

Notice that the distances $BY$ and $BX$ are equal, and the distances $CX$ and $CZ$ are equal.

So a segment of length more than $BY$ and one of length more than $CZ$ have a sum of lengths more than $BY+YC$, thus satisfying the triangle inequality.

Comment: Why are the distances between CX and CZ equal?

Comment: Through every point (such as $C$) exterior to the circle, one can draw two lines tangent to the circle.  The distances from $C$ to the two points of tangency are equal.

Comment: All right, let's try a slightly less intuitive approach: Let $C$ be exterior to the circle; let $X$ and $Z$ be the points of tangency on the two lines through $C$ that are tangent to the circle; let $P$ be the center.  The two radii $PX$ and $PZ$ have equal lengths (by definition of "circle") and meet the tangents at right angles. So we have the two triangles $\triangle CPX$ and $\triangle CPZ$, with two side lengths in common and each with a right angle. Thus "S.S.A.", with the "A." begin a right angle. The Pythagorean theorem then says $CX^2 = CP^2 - PX^2 = CP^2 - PZ^2 = CZ^2$. ${}\qquad{}$